# Assign column names to a data.table whose name is selected from another data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have to assign column names to a series of data tables of which the names are stored in another data.table (interpret this as a configuration table). E.g., in the example below, I want to name the 2 columns of `DT1` 'id' and 'name'. I know that I have to name the columns of `DT1` as such, because `DT1` is in `DT2`:

```
col1 = 1:5
col2 = LETTERS[1:5]
DT1 = data.table(col1, col2)

id = 1
name = "DT1"
DT2 = data.table(id, name)

columnNames = c('ID', 'Letter')
```

I can do this with

```
DT3 = eval(as.name(DT2[1, name]))
colnames(DT3) = columnNames 

x = DT2[1, name]

assign(x, DT3)
```

I don't like this, however, as I copy `DT1` to `DT3`, which will slow my program down.

Obviously, this does not work:

```
colnames(eval(as.name(DT2[1, name]))) = columnNames
colnames(get(DT2[1, name])) = columnNames
```

Is there a way to assign column names to a data.table (when the name of the data.table can only be selected from another data.table) without copying the data.table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.table::setnames`:

```
setnames(get(DT2[1, name]), columnNames)
DT1
#   id Letter
#1:  1      A
#2:  2      B
#3:  3      C
#4:  4      D
#5:  5      E
```